# Select timestamps with different field names from two tables, and order them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked at some other questions here but can't find a solution that matches mine. I don't really understand some of the parts so I can't adapt their solutions to my problem.

I have a table like this:

`post_id, post_author, post_message, post_timestamp, post_thread`
and.. `thread_id, thread_author, thread_message, thread_timestamp` and I'd like to fetch * from both (different) tables, and order by their timestamp so I could fetch the latest from both.

How can I achieve this? As I said I looked into some other solutions here but can't adapt it as the ones I can find, have the same name on their timestamp field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the two tables have a shared key? You'll need something to join them on so you know which rows in the `message` table match which rows in the the `somethingelse` table.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the latest entry from _each of those_ or just from _one of them_?

Comment: I updated my question, basically it's an forum and I'd like to show the latest posts (but also include topics in that) The topics and replies (posts) are two different tables. And I'd like to get the latest 10 activity (both posts/topics)

Comment: Sounds like each post belongs to one thread, and you want the 10 threads which have had a post most recently?

Comment: Yeah but a thread could have zero replies, so I can't only go by the replies/posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use a `LEFT JOIN` from thread to post, and you can sort using a `coalesce`. The performance will probably be horrible, but let's get something working first and then tune it.

```
SELECT p.*, t.*, coalesce(p.post_timestamp, t.thread_timestamp) as timestamp FROM thread t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as p on p.post_thread = t.thread_id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
;
```

The `coalesce` function takes a list of arguments and returns the first one that's not null. So in this case, it will return the post timestamp, unless there is no post, in which case it will return the thread timestamp. The join is a LEFT join so that even if the subselect returns zero results, there will still be a result row.

Comment: It seems to fetch them correctly. If it's a post, how would I go about to grab the topics field topic_name? Or would I do a new query based on post_topic? And how do I learn about this stuff as I'm not really 100% understanding what's going on. :^

Comment: You have access to any of the fields from post or topic by referencing `p.whatever` or `t.whatever`. If there are other tables you want to join to, you could add additional left joins based on fields from p, like `LEFT JOIN widget w ON p.widget_id = w.id`, and then you could add fields from `w` to your select statement.

Comment: As far as how to learn, try using "mysql join", "mysql subselect" or "mysql coalesce" as search terms to find resources.